# Image in a beamer block

Tags: beamer, graphics

I insert an image in a block. When I increase the size of the image the size of block decrease. I do not understand what happen?

```
\documentclass[compress,red]{beamer}
\usepackage{etex}
\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}%les accents pour mac
%\usepackage{caption} 
%\captionsetup{font=small}
%\captionsetup{labelformat=empty}
 \usepackage{subfigure}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{array,ragged2e}
 \usepackage{setspace}
 \usepackage{multirow} 
 %\usepackage{subcaption}
  \begin{document}
  \section{section1 }
  \frame[shrink]{\frametitle{Titre de la fenetre}

  \begin{block}{Scénario 2}
  \begin{figure}[!h]
  \centering
   \fbox{
    \mbox{\subfigure[Vue 1]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{image1.png}}  \quad \quad 
       \subfigure[Vue 2]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{image1.png}}}}
    %\caption{Reconstruction 3D:Scénario 2}
    \end{figure}
    \end{block} 
    \begin{block}{Scénario 2}
     \begin{figure}[!h]
      \centering
       \fbox{
         \mbox{\subfigure[Vue 1]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{image1.png}}  \quad \quad 
        \subfigure[Vue 2]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{image1.png}}}}
          %\caption{Reconstruction 3D:Scénario 2}
        \end{figure}
        \end{block}

         }
         \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you construct a minimal example document to show what you mean?

Comment: @AlanMunn sorry, I edited my code.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I'm still not quite sure I understand your problem, though.

Comment: @AlanMunn, In fact I need that the two block occupy all the width why they are too small. I know that they are so big and when I delete the shrink option, the block 2 will depass the frame. but how I can increase juste the width of the block.

Comment: The `shrink` option shrinks everything, which is why it is "evil" (according to the Beamer manual). Can you adjust the `height` of the images instead of the `width`?

Comment: @AlanMunn, Exacly, I am doing it but when I change the image height. It debords the block!!! usually, we have a problem!!!

Comment: If I adjust the height and width correctly, and don't use `[shrink]` the block size doesn't change.

Comment: @AlanMunn, But we can loose the image quality. A lot of constraints

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

The `[shrink]` option shrinks everything which is why the Beamer manual calls it "evil". The only way to do what you want is to not use the `[shrink]` option and then adjust the height and width of the images to fit the actual block space you have to work with.  As you note, in the comments, this may affect the image quality, but there's really no other solution in this case:

```
\documentclass[compress,red,demo]{beamer}
\usepackage{etex}
\mode<presentation>
\usetheme[]{Warsaw}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%les accents pour mac
 \usepackage{subfigure}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
  \begin{document}
  \section{section1 }
  \frame{\frametitle{Titre de la fenetre}

  \begin{block}{Scénario 2}
  \begin{figure}[!h]
  \centering
   \fbox{
    \mbox{\subfigure[Vue 1]{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm,width=2cm]{image1.png}}  \quad \quad 
       \subfigure[Vue 2]{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm,width=2cm]{image1.png}}}}
    %\caption{Reconstruction 3D:Scénario 2}
    \end{figure}
    \end{block} 
    \begin{block}{Scénario 2}
     \begin{figure}[!h]
      \centering
       \fbox{
         \mbox{\subfigure[Vue 1]{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm,width=2cm]{image1.png}}  \quad \quad 
        \subfigure[Vue 2]{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm,width=2cm]{image1.png}}}}
          %\caption{Reconstruction 3D:Scénario 2}
        \end{figure}
        \end{block}

         }
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]